# how can I remove a row if a given keyword is not found in the first column?

Tags: javascript, datatable

I am trying to remove a row from my datatable if a given `job_title` is not found , but I am getting `table.row(...).delete is not a function`

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var keywords = ['aslr', 'ida pro', 'gdb', 'windbg', 'immunity debugger', 'boofuzz', 'peach fuzzer', 'winafl', 'python', 'assembly', 'penetration testing', 'exploits', 'metasploit', 'metasploit framework', 'ethical hacker', 'pentest', 'computer security', 'hacking', 'oscp', 'osce', 'osee', 'penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'mitre att&ck', 'vulnerability research', 'vulnerability researcher', 'fuzzing', 'clang', 'llvm', 'address sanitizer', 'afl', 'fuzzers','penetration tester']
    var job_title = ['penetration tester','penetration testing', 'offensive security', 'vulnerability researcher','software','security','developer','ethical hacker','cyberSécurité','threat','it Security','application security','information security','security engineer','product security','cyber security','software engineer']
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/index_get_data",
            "dataType": "json",
            "dataSrc": "jobs",
            "contentType":"application/json"
        },
        columnDefs: [{
            targets: 0,
            render: function (data,row) {
              for (var i = 0; i < job_title.length; i += 1) {
                if (data.indexOf(job_title[i])) {
                  console.log("FOUND")
                }else{
                  table.row( this ).delete();
                }
              }
            }
        },{
            targets: 4,
            render: function (data) {
              for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i += 1) {
                if (data.indexOf(keywords[i])) {
                  return "<span class='label label-success'>FOUND</span>";
                }
              }
              return "<span class='label label-danger'>NOT_FOUND</span>";
            }
        },{
          targets: 5,
            render: function (data) {
                return '<a href="'+data+'">Link</a>'
            }
        }],
        "columns": [
            {"data": "job_title"},
            {"data": "company"},
            {"data": "city"},
            {"data": "date"},
            {"data": "job_description"},
            {"data": "url"},
        ]
    });
    setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload( null, false );
    }, 30000 );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `rowCallback` here.

[Refer this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/48354/hide-a-row-before-rendering-if-data-specific-column-contains-null) 
`rowCallback Doc`

[Refer this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback)